# ul.dropdown-menu only shows on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my bootstrap ul.dropdown-menu in my header-menu. I have a li-item with a dropdown, but the dropdown only shows then I hover the li-item.

How can I make it, so it only shows on click and stay until I click on the li-item again or anywhere else?

I had made many Google search's, but I can't find the answer. Thise exampels on Bootstrap's website, have the same classes as my header menu.

```
<ul id="menu-primary" class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto custom-ul"><li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-5305" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-5305 nav-item show"><a title="Item 1" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-5305">Item 1</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu show" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-5305" role="menu">
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-5321" class="custom-dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5321 nav-item"><a title="Dropdown item 1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-5322" class="custom-dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5322 nav-item"><a title="Dropdown item 2" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown item 2</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-5323" class="custom-dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5323 nav-item"><a title="Dropdown item 3" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown item 3</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-5324" class="custom-dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5324 nav-item"><a title="Dropdown item 4" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-5316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5316 nav-item"><a title="Item 2" href="#" class="nav-link">Item 2</a></li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-5299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5299 nav-item"><a title="Item 3" href="#" class="nav-link">Item 3</a></li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-5302" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5302 nav-item"><a title="Item 4" href="#" class="nav-link">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you click on the dropdown item, it shows a dropdown, but it disappear after removing the mouse. I want the dropdown to stay, until I click on the parent-li again or anywhere else on the website.

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: your code working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/90qhfn7d/1/

Comment: I could not find a specific solution, but I solved it with this code:
`.nav li.et-touch-hover>ul, .nav li>ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav li.et-touch-hover>ul, .nav li:hover>ul {
    visibility: unset !important;
    opacity: 1;
}`